# Create grid creates wrong grid using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

[image]

The yellow polygon is my working area that I draw. I have a small plugin. The user enter the row and column number than create a grid. This row and column number is used to find the `Horizontal Spacing` and `Vertical Spacing` because `qgis:creategrid` function wants them. xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax are derived from the working area polygon - `layer.extent().xMinimum` and others. At last  `crs` is derived from canvas, as well.

As it is seen, all neccassary values are entered. However, in this example, I entered 4 columns, 2 rows but it creates one more rows. It is true for my working area but I do not want to additional row. By the way, wrong additional grids place can change randomly (one more column, one more column and row etc.).

Derived paramters are true because I print the values in python console and use them to create grid, It works. Here is my code:

```
def createGrid(self, dx, dy, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, epsg, layer):
layerList = list(range(1, layer + 1))
for katman in layerList:
    parameters = {'TYPE': 2,
                  'EXTENT': '%f,%f,%f,%f' % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                  'HSPACING': dx,
                  'VSPACING': dy,
                  'HOVERLAY': 0.0,
                  'VOVERLAY': 0.0,
                  'CRS': str(epsg),
                  'OUTPUT': QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition(
                      self._gv.karelajDir + "/Grid" + str(katman) + ".shp")}
    processing.run('qgis:creategrid', parameters)

    self.gridLayer = QgsVectorLayer(self._gv.karelajDir + "/Grid" + str(katman) + ".shp", "Grid" + str(katman),
                                    "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.gridLayer)
```

It creates grid amount of layer (entered by user).